# How do I Find a string in a file and place a string above it?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to find the String `__MARKER__` in `someFile.txt` and place a String above it (e.g. `Hello World!`).

How would I do that using `sed`?

```
sed -i -e "/__MARKER__//g" someFile.txt # Currently removes __MARKER__.
```

Contents of `someFile.txt`:

```
__MARKER__
```

Contents of `someFile.txt` after manipulation:

```
Hello World!
__MARKER__
```

Comment: This question was cross-posted to Ask Different https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/327258/37797

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/__MARKER__/Hello world\n&/' someFile.txt
```

replaces `__MARKER__` with `Hello world`, a newline, and the match (`&`), i.e. the text `__MARKER__`.

The `&` just saves typing `__MARKER__` again, as in

```
sed -i -e 's/__MARKER__/Hello world\n__MARKER__/' someFile.txt
```

Comment: After running `sed -i -e 's/__MARKER__/Hello world\n&/' someFile.txt` the contents of `someFile.txt` is `Hello worldn__MARKER__`.

Comment: That's weird because for me it works exactly as I've written and I didn't escape any backslashes (by doubling them). It just worked as is. Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

If there is only a single instance of `__MARKER__` **or** you want to insert the new string before every instance, you can use

```
sed -i '/__MARKER__/ iHello World!' someFile.txt
```

This uses the **i**nsert command rather than the **s**ubstitute command - note that on POSIX (non-GNU) `sed` you may need to put the insert string on a separate line:

```
sed -i '/__MARKER__/ i\
Hello World!
' someFile.txt
```

If there are multiple instances, and you only wish to insert the string before the first one, then

```
sed -i '0,/__MARKER__/ s//Hello World!\n&/' someFile.txt
```

Comment: Produces error: `unterminated substitute pattern.`

Comment: @NicholasAdamou are you actually using Ubuntu? GNU sed? what is the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: I'm running MacOS.

Comment: @NicholasAdamou then the forum for you is apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NicholasAdamou https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256615/108199